# Using pyarrow 8.0.0 to search for a nested field in an array

Tags: python, pyarrow, minio

I would like to search looking for a match in MinIO storage with pyarrow 8.0.0 and python 3.8 because in this version the programmers implemented a nested search.
The problem I am currently encountering is that when I am searching for a value in a struct inside a list it does not work.

My schema is as follows:

```
Features: list<element: struct<Feature: struct<Id: int64, Core: string, Building: int32>, Value: double>>
Object: struct<Id: int64, Core: string, Building: int32>
Time: timestamp[ns]
Name: string
```

If I execute these queries:

```py
ds.field("Features", "Feature", "Id").isin([3])
```

```py
ds.field("Object", "Id").isin([3])
```

The first one returns this error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: No match for FieldRef.Nested(FieldRef.Name(Features) FieldRef.Name(Feature) FieldRef.Name(Id)) in 
Time: timestamp[ns]
Features: list<element: struct<Feature: struct<Id: int64, Core: string, Building: int32>, Value: double>>
Name: string
Object: struct<Id: int64, Core: string, Building: int32>
```

The second one instead works as expected.

Is there a problem with the nested fields inside lists?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `pyarrow.dataset.Expression` will work on `list` fields.

I think it's in part because it is ambiguous:

- Do you want to keep rows  where all Features.Feature.Id are in the set?
- Rows where any Features.Feature.Id is in the set?
- Or out of these record you only want to keep the nested Feature that where in the set?

You can try to emulate the same behaviour with [pyarrow.compute](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html), but it's not trivial. The code below select the rows where any `Features.Feature.Id` is int the the input set (`[3]`):

```py
import pyarrow.compute as pc


flat_list = pc.list_flatten(table["Features"])
flat_id = pc.struct_field(flat_list, indices=[flat_list.type.get_field_index("Id")])
flat_indices = pc.is_in(flat_id, pa.array([3]))

flat_parent_indices = pc.take(pc.unique(pc.list_parent_indices(table["Features"])), flat_indices)
table.take(flat_parent_indices)
```